What is meaning of forms in "they are even used as coil forms for inductors?"
From the resistor introduction in The Art of Electronics third edition:

Resistors are truly ubiquitous. There are almost as many
types as there are applications. Resistors are used in amplifiers
as loads for active devices, in bias networks, and
as feedback elements. In combination with capacitors
they establish time constants and act as filters. They are
used to set operating currents and signal levels. Resistors
are used in power circuits to reduce voltages by dissipating
power, to measure currents, and to discharge capacitors
after power is removed. They are used in precision
circuits to establish currents, to provide accurate
voltage ratios, and to set precise gain values. In logic circuits
they act as bus and line terminators and as “pullup”
and “pull-down” resistors. In high-voltage circuits they
are used to measure voltages and to equalize leakage currents
among diodes or capacitors connected in series. In
radiofrequency (RF) circuits they set the bandwidth of
resonant circuits, and they are even used as coil forms
for inductors.

In the last line of above paragraph, I don't know how to understand forms.
Which meaning of forms is used here, or is there another meaning?

When manufacturing inductive coils, resistors are used as molds, serving as the supporting structure for the inductor coil and helping to maintain the shape of the coil.

To be the thing, or one of the things, that is part of something else, often having a particular use, namely resistors as part of inductors.


Maybe the second meaning is wrong, especially "resistors as part of inductors", because inductors are only made from coils. For first meaning, molds can be replace with other the shape of the coil, so I'm confused.

"Former" is a somewhat more traditional word in this context.

@MarkMorganLloyd  Thank you for your comment. I think in here "Former" is better understand than "form".

Here, from 1957, is an example of a carbon ('composition' type probably) resistor used as an inexpensive and easy-to-source coil form  (or 'former', I'm not sure there's a generally accepted definition of 'form' vs. 'former' in this context).
The resistor serves no electrical purpose- it's just a stable non-magnetic bobbin on which to wind the coil (also providing firmly attached leads), and the resistance value is chosen to be high enough that the 'Q' of the coil is not significantly impacted. In this case, the outer resistor body would be phenolic which has excellent electrical properties.

From this vintage Allen-Bradley catalog we have a depiction of the internal construction- the element is just bulk material inside a "hot-molded" insulating shell.

Modern film resistors may not be as good for this purpose- the end caps and leads tend to be ferromagnetic (because iron is cheaper than copper) and the bodies are covered by a thin layer of lacquer. The spiral element being so close to the coil turns might also have some ill effects since it is relatively low resistivity (there is a long spiral rather than a bulk resistance) and may even be magnetic in the case of metal film resistors.

Thank you for your answer, I think it is right about "The resistor serves no electrical purpose".

I think "former" is usefull for me, I look coil form and coil former in dictionary and found they seem be the same thing, I should see coil form as one thing. Now I truely understand what is "coil form". Thank you very much.

As coil form (in picture maybe is 470X2WATTT ), the purpose is for inductors (symbol is L), add images to assist in the explanation, making it clear and easy to understand. You're an expert!

For inductors, the word "form" is used for the thing you wind the coil on.  It is what gives form to the coil while winding it.

In some inductors, the form is removed after winding.  These are usually coils made of stiff wire that will keep its shape without the form.
In some inductors, the form remains in the inductor after winding.  These inductors usually have fine wire or are very small - the wire can't hold the coil shape by itself.
In some inductors, the form is part of the inductor.  The form in such cases may be of metal or pressed ferrite particles.  The metal or ferrite core increases the inductance, making it possible to get a higher inductance in a smaller volume.

Hobbyists used to wind their own inductors rather than order a specific value from a manufacturer.  In such hand made parts, it was common to wind the inductor around the body of a resistor.  If the wire was stiff, you could later remove the resistor.  If not, the carbon composition contruction of the resistor body meant that it wouldn't have any noticeable effect on the inductance of the coil.

In really olden days, people made simple AM radios using large air-core coils.  They would wind the coil around a cylinder shaped box of oatmeal, then remove the box when the coil was complete.
The oatmeal box was the form.

Now I see, thank you for your answer.

Modern folks use a Pringles® can.

@pipe Hi, what is meaning of "Modern folks use a Pringles® can. ".

@Tom, Pipe is referring to the large tube that would be used to create the tuning coil for a crystal radio. A Pringles potato chip can is a long cylinder, about 75mmx250mm.

@JBH Thank you for your explanation, link in your comment is useful, about "A Pringles potato chip can", I don't understand well, I think can is container just like "a closed metal container with round sides, for food or drinks. It is opened with a can opener.". I know what is chip, it like cpu of computer and smart phone. Does Pringles  refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pringles, Does potato refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato#:~:text=Potatoes%20are%20underground%20tubers%20of,Scientific%20classification or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato_(disambiguation) ?

@Tom Your link to Wikipedia's entry for Pringles is correct. Here's an Amazon link to the can of Pringles chips that shows you the shape of the can. The cans (containers) come in different lengths but always the same diameter. The first Wikipedia entry for Potato is the vegetable, though this might make more sense. Pringles chips are famous for their shape. The can/container is a tube, closed at both ends. Used as an inductor form, the ends would be removed.

@JBH 1/2) I seem to understand mean that you said, in "A Pringles potato chip can", the core(or most important) word is can, "can" in here as container, it is red object in https://imgse.com/i/pAb4EHf . Pringles in here is brand(or trademark) and I think brand in here is meaning of "a product or group of products that has its own name and is made by one particular company.". Then "Potato chip" should view as whole and "chip" in here is not meaning of thing that like "cpu of computer and smart phone", "chip" in here is meaning of "a long thin piece of potato cooked in hot oil.".

@JBH 2/2) So you  want to express is inductor form is thing just like a Pringles potato chip can that it is red object in https://imgse.com/i/pAb4EHf . Is my understanding correct?

@Tom Correct! And well done with the analysis.

@JBH Thank you so much for your patient explanation.

A Pringles can is lined with foil -- this, plus their fortuitous dimensions, makes them famously suitable as WiFi antennas. But it also makes them unsuitable as coil forms, because the foil acts as a shorted turn. The oatmeal box is much better for this reason. (Also, the oatmeal box is normally kept in place, since the wire used for the coil is usually rather thin.)

To be entirely accurate, when a resistor is used as a form for an inductor, what you get (if the inductor is connected to the resistor at both ends) is a parallel LR circuit.
A long time ago I built a kit audio amplifier in which there was such a circuit in the output, to help with stability. You had to wind about 10 turns of wire onto a fairly large power resistor, then solder the ends of the wire to the resistor legs. This was an example of a resistor providing the form for an inductor.

Thank you for your answer, but I think "LR circuit" maybe is not apposite in here.

If L and R are in parallel, it is an LR circuit. Whether R has much effect is another matter (that depends on the values), but it is still an LR circuit.

I truely understand what is "coil form", it is the same as "coil former".
